# Why is my variable inaccessible inside the class function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change value of variable defined in constructor from class function. When I try to change it or print it, everything I get is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'daysNumber' of undefined

I'm not sure, but I think this can be happening because of calling this function in unusual way.

I'm calling functions based on options I get in constructor. So if one of the options is **weekends**, called function is **setWeekends**.

Error is happening inside of **setWeekends** function.

```
"use strict";

class Calendar{
    constructor(element, params){
        this.element = element;
        this.params = params;
        this.parseParams();
        this.date = new Date();
        this.days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
        this.teachingHoursRange = ['7:10-7:55', '8:00-8:45', '8:50-9:35', '9:45-10:30', '10:50-11:35', '11:40-12:25', '12:30-13:15', '13:20-14:05', '14:10-14:55', '15:00-15:45'];
        // How many days will be displayed
        this.daysNumber = 5;
        // How many hours will be displayed
        this.teachingHoursNumber = 10;
        this.init();
    }

    init(){
        // Some important code
    }

    parseParams(){
        // Look for all parameters in this.params
        for (let key in this.params){
            // Make the first char capitalize
            let capitalizedKey = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            let functionName = "set" + capitalizedKey;

            // Look for member function set by function name
            let fn = this[functionName];

            // If fn is function, call it
            if (typeof fn === 'function') fn(this.params[key])

        }
    }

    setWeekends(value){
        if(value === true)
            this.daysNumber = 7
    }
}
```

This is the source code where I call this class. It's in the different .js file.

```
let calendar = new Calendar("calendar", {
    weekends: true
});
```

Comment: add the code where you called `setWeekends` and where you called the constuctor

Comment: Where do you call `calendar.setWeekends()`?

Comment: @frozen Okay, source code is updated.

Comment: show where you call `calendar.setWeekends()`

Comment: `setWeekends()` is called in `parseParams` function. It parses all of the options, add prefix *set*, make the first char uppercase and it's called by string.

Comment: you are calling this.parseParams(); before initialising  this.daysNumber = 5;   swap place and you will get the result

Comment: `let fn = this[functionName]`

Comment: @AmitpalRawat That's not the problem. It's not complaining that the property doesn't exist, it's complaining that `this` is undefined.

Comment: I've already tried it before, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly. I forgot to mention this. In init function, `this` returns the whole class. In `parseParams` it returns `undefined`

Comment: ohh i get it. the problem is this function is acting like a callback function so it will not recognise this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the context when calling the function in `parseParams()`. You can do this by using the `.call()` method to call the function.

```
parseParams(){
    // Look for all parameters in this.params
    for (let key in this.params){
        // Make the first char capitalize
        let capitalizedKey = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.substr(1).toLowerCase();
        let functionName = "set" + capitalizedKey;

        // Look for member function set by function name
        let fn = this[functionName];

        // If fn is function, call it
        if (typeof fn === 'function') fn.call(this, this.params[key])

    }
}
```

Comment: Great, It works! But why there's no context when other functions which are not called based on string it has?

Comment: @JanSedlon the normal way to call a method is `object.function(params)`, that passes `object` as the context. If you just call `function(params)` there's no `object` before it, so there's no context.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

change your `setWeekends` method to

```
setWeekends = (value) => {
    if(value === true)
        this.daysNumber = 7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
parseParams(){
     let vm = this;
        // Look for all parameters in this.params
        for (let key in this.params){
            // Make the first char capitalize
            let capitalizedKey = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            let functionName = "set" + capitalizedKey;

            // Look for member function set by function name
            let fn = this[functionName];

            // If fn is function, call it
            if (typeof fn === 'function') fn(vm, this.params[key])

        }
    }


setWeekends(vm, value){
        if(value === true)
            vm.daysNumber = 7
    }
```